# "Shop by" sort order of attributes on category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes

Is there a way to change the sort order of the "shop by" attributes?

I tried changing the order in the attribute set, but that does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the sort order on the individual attribute:

```
admin > catalog > attributes > manage attributes > attribute
```

In the attribute you edit the "Position" setting

Remember to re-index afterwards.

Comment: Ah perfect. Forgot about that spot.